# Read text file using multithread pool in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want to read a file containing 6 lines of integers separated with commas. Each time I use a thread pool, they read the same line. I want each thread to quickSort one line each, save it in a file. After which method mergeSort will sort them.

```
 public class myclass2 extends myclass {
 public static void main(String [] arg){
 final myclass obj=new myclass();

        System.out.println("Enter number of threads you want to instantiate\n");
        Scanner handle=new Scanner (System.in);
        final int no=handle.nextInt();
         ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(no);
         for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) 
         {
             System.out.println(i);
                threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         obj.runProgram(no);
                     }
                 });
         }
         System.out.println("Before merge sort in myclass 2");
         obj.mergesort();
             // once you've submitted your last job to the service it should be shut down
             threadPool.shutdown();



        handle.close();
}
}
```

Code of runProgram method is below. It reads from Data.txt, quickSorts it and then saves it in a file.

```
   public void runProgram(int no)
   {

    Scanner handleforfile=null;
    String recFromFile=null;
    FileWriter x=null;
    try {
        int check=0;
        check++;
        if(check<2)
        {
            File fileobj= new File("Data.txt");
            handleforfile=new Scanner(fileobj);

            FileWriter handle=new FileWriter("ThreadingData.txt",true);
            BufferedWriter bwhandle1=new BufferedWriter(handle);
            x=handle;
            handle.close();
        }
                 if(handleforfile.hasNext())
                 {
                    for(int i=0;i<check;i++)
                    {
                     recFromFile=handleforfile.nextLine();//reads the line req
                    }
                     System.out.println("Rec line from file"+recFromFile);//rec data from file
                     String[] numberStrs = recFromFile.split(",");//convert it into now int[]
                        int[] numbers = new int[numberStrs.length];
                        for(int ik = 0;ik < numberStrs.length;ik++)
                        {
                           numbers[ik] = Integer.parseInt(numberStrs[ik]);
                           System.out.println(numbers[ik]);

                        }

                        System.out.println("converted into int[]");
                        quickSort(numbers,0,numbers.length-1);
                        String temp=Arrays.toString(numbers);
                        System.out.println(temp);
                        BufferedWriter bwhandle=new BufferedWriter(x);
                        try {
                            bwhandle.write(temp.substring(1,temp.length()-1));//avoids brakets////////////////
                            bwhandle.write('\n');
                            //bwhandle.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            System.out.println("here in myclass");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                 }//end if
                 else
                 {
                     System.out.println("returning");
                     return;
                 }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("here in myclass2");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("here in myclass3");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that each thread creates a separate instance of scanner, pointing to the file and hence each will start from the first line,

```
File fileobj= new File("Data.txt");
handleforfile=new Scanner(fileobj);
```

If you want each thread to read corresponding line, then create only one instance of scanner and co-ordinate the threads access.

Comment: Where should I make them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file in a main thread, split it up into lines, give each line to another thread to sort and then merge it again afterwards.

There is no point having a multi-thread read of the file as the threads would have to synchronise and in this case, there isn't enough data to make it worth while.

If you had huge blocks of lines, you could make your main thread locate the block boundaries and then tell the subthreads where to start reading, but it might still be quicker to have the main thread do all of the reading (otherwise you risk reading the file twice).

This is basically *map-reduce*.

You are considering the *input reader* phase. See [MapReduce#Input_reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce#Input_reader)